# Assistance data injection into GPS

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, supl

I am trying to develop an application which uses GPS and I would like to inject XTRA data and time  reference to the GPS in order to get a faster fix. My code is the following one:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
boolean xtraInjection=locationmanager.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,"force_xtra_injection",bundle);
boolean timeInjection=locationmanager.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,"force_time_injection",bundle);
```

No matter whether internet connection is on or off (no cellular neither wifi) the xtraInjection and timeInjection booleans are always true. So, I not able to detect if the assistance information is well
injected into the GPS.

When the wifi connection is enabled, the next log message appears (no error message if wifi is down):

```
I/app (  627): timeInjection:true
....
D/GpsLocationProvider(   96): NTP server returned: 1306322421969 (WedMay 25 13:20:21 GMT+02:00 2011) reference: 338139 certainty: 77 systemtime offset: 7162
D/lib_locapi( 96): loc_eng_inject_time, uncertainty = 77
```

In contrast, there is no log message related with XTRA data. If the XTRA data is still valid, the system does not request for it? How can I see if it is injected successfully?

To make these tests I have also tried deleting assistance data but I know that this is not well done:

My code:

```
boolean reset=locationmanager.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, "delete_aiding_data", null);
```

log:

```
I/app (  627): reset:false
D/lib_locapi(   96): loc_eng_ioctl for aiding data deletion returned 0, 1 for success
```

I have also tried with GPS STATUS application and the results are the same for both, inject and delete.

In short, I do not know whether the problem is in my code or is something in the driver implementation. There is any way to obtain more information about these problems apart from logcat? (I can not root my device).

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at `frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/location/GpsLocationProvider.java`, you'll find that these commands will always return true.

There is very little reason why you should be doing this, and a few reasons why you shouldn't:

- Android will automatically inject time and XTRA data when the network first comes up after booting. Time should not need to be re-injected as the GPS chip will synchronise its internal clock with GPS whenever it has a fix. The GPS chip will automatically request new XTRA data when needed.
- XTRA is only applicable to the Qualcomm GPS chipset. The other vendors do have equivalent services but these are not exposed in GpsLocationProvider like XTRA is.
- Chances are that an Internet connection will be available. In this case, the GPS will just download ephemerides from the SUPL server when needed, only falling back to XTRA when this is not possible.

Comment: Quick question...  Why are chances that an internet connection will be available?

Comment: had to vote down, there are many apps that can be downloaded that appear to do just this thing, and they make the connecting to GPS faster.  Also though many phones are the target, quite a few people may target devices that are only connected when say the hardware is at the base.  (thinking enterprise apps)

Comment: There are indeed valid use cases. One is when you know you're going to be without a data connection. Let's say you're abroad and have disabled data roaming, but you have WiFi connectivity at some places – at your hotel, a public hotspot or similar. In that case you can manually download the AGPS data when you have WiFi access and will be able to work with that for some time. Without this, you wouldn't be able to use AGPS and would wait for up to 20 minutes to get a fix.