# How to check whether Android device GPS module has A-GPS support

Tags: android, gps, hardware

To force download AGPS data I have to execute following code:

```
LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService("location");
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
locationmanager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_xtra_injection", bundle);
locationmanager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_time_injection", bundle);
```

Is this possible to check if device has AGPS support? I want to be sure, that executing this piece of code is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That hack is not needed at all normally, and that's why it's not in the regular API. Here you can read [a superb answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127446/813951).

But even if a certain device doesn't support it, calling those methods won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

To check if it has hardware support use this:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean hasGps = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
```

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I know how to check GPS support, but how to check if GPS supports AGPS?